# The list of 5-element sets can you make with 2 elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matlab

Take the set $\{1,2\}$. I know there are $2^5 = 32$ different 5-element sets made up these two elements, but what are they?

I would like to create a $32 \times 5$ matrix in MATLAB or MuPad such that each row contains each set. For example the first row could be [1 2 2 1 1] and the second [2 2 2 1 1] etc.

I know these are neither combinations nor permutations, so what would you call such an arrangement? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think you mean 5-elements arrangements, vectors or something else, because as **sets** we have that $\;\{1,2\}=\{2,1\}=\{1,1,1,2,1,2,2\}\;$ , etc.

Comment: Ahh! You're right, what a stupid mistake, thanks. Searching through the MATLAB webpage for arrangements gives me results much closer to what I want, but the problem remains that when I try to call nchoosek([1 2],5) or anything else it returns and empty matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a magical way to do this:

```
b = de2bi((0:31)') + 1;
```

Comment: This feels like cheating! :D (+1)

Comment: Oh you're good! Thank you very much!

Comment: For those not acquainted with Matlab idiosyncrasies : de2bi=de-to-bi=decimal to binary.